# transfer tkinter entry results

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created an entry field in a function and want to access the output of this entry field in the next function. how is this possible?

```
def test1():
    registerfenster = Toplevel()
    entry_bn_rg = Entry(registerfenster, width=30)
    entry_bn_rg.pack()
    btn_register_rg = Button(registerfenster, text="Register", bg="white", width=10, 
                             command=test2)
    btn_register_rg.pack()

def test2():
    global entry_bn_rg
    test123 = entry_bn_rg.get()
    if test123 == "Hello":
        print("Sucess")
```

Comment: Put `global entry_bn_rg` in *both* functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
bn_rg = StringVar() # if its str or bn_rg = IntVar() if its int, this is your entry input variable


def test1():
    registerfenster = Toplevel()
    entry_bn_rg = Entry(registerfenster, textvariable = bn_rg, width=30)
    entry_bn_rg.pack()
    btn_register_rg = Button(registerfenster, text="Register", bg="white", width=10, command=test2)
    btn_register_rg.pack()

def test2():
    
    test123 = bn_rg.get()
    if test123 == "Hello":
        print("Sucess")
```

Viel Glück

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, put the line: "global entry_bn_rg" in the first function "test1", not the second. Just like this:

```
def test1():
    global entry_bn_rg
    registerfenster = Toplevel()
    entry_bn_rg = Entry(registerfenster, width=30)
    entry_bn_rg.pack()
    btn_register_rg = Button(registerfenster, text="Register", bg="white", width=10, command=test2)
    btn_register_rg.pack()

def test2():
    test123 = entry_bn_rg.get()
    if test123 == "Hello":
        print("Sucess")
```